# arrange arrays inside arrays on basis of a value

Tags: php

i have an array of arrays like below the length of the arrays will be unknown i want to sort the arrays in ascending order on basis of the third element in every array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => AbdulA
            [2] => TEST White Truck 7 am 9:30 am 12 pm 2:30 pm
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
            [1] => AbdulAnn
            [2] => TEST White Truck 7 am 9:30 am 12 pm 2:30 pm
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => pacha
            [2] => TEST RED TRUCK
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: `usort` with a comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a[3] - $b[3];
}
usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: @haidar I got your other question working! (sorry to hijack)